# What tool can I use to transform a binary file to and from plain text?

Tags: attachments, binary-files, plaintext

I would like to send a binary (PDF) file through a channel that supports plain text only.

Is there a multi-platform standard tool that will convert the binary file into a chunk of plain text so that I can send it in this form, and have the other user transform it back to binary afterwards?

Comment: `uuencode`? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding

Comment: uuencode works.